# Nested element inside ion-item not showing

Tags: ionic-framework

I'm new in Ionic and I want to create list in which in each ion-item there will be checbox and when user checks it then select will appear in new line but still within ion-item. I've tried to use ion-item inside ion-item but then select wasn't showing. I've read that there is some issue with nested ion-items so I replaced first ion-item with ng-container but after that all layout looks terrible. What should I do?

```
  <ion-list>
      <ng-container *ngFor="let filter of filters">
          <ion-label> {{filter.name}}</ion-label>
          <ion-checkbox item-right [(ngModel)]="filter.checked" (ionChange)="onCheckboxChange($event, filter)"></ion-checkbox>
          <ion-item>
            <ion-select [(ngModel)]="option">
              <ion-option *ngFor="let option of filter.data" [value]="option">{{option.name}}</ion-option>
            </ion-select>
          </ion-item>
        </ng-container>
  </ion-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out - in ion-list I put ion-card-content with ngFor as a wrapper for ion-items. Works and looks good!

```
  <ion-list>
    <ion-card-content *ngFor="let filter of filters" class="card-wrapper">
      <ion-item class="checkbox-item">
        <ion-label> {{filter.name}}</ion-label>
        <ion-checkbox item-right [(ngModel)]="filter.checked"></ion-checkbox>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-select [(ngModel)]="option">
          <ion-option *ngFor="let option of filter.data" [value]="option">{{option.name}}</ion-option>
        </ion-select>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-card-content>
  </ion-list>
```